# objective-c Including category in another category

Tags: objective-c, import, categories

I have for exemple a view login, and two category : login+checkLogin and login+startConnection

The category connection use a method of the checkLogin category when it's finish. So I have a warning which tell me that the checkLogin method is not found.
So to silent the warning, I import in the connection category the checkLogin category.

It is normal or is there an another solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the .h file which defines the category, presumably `Login+CheckLogin.h`, so that the implementation of the other category method has visibility.

Comment: Yes it is what I did. I Just wondering if it was normal to import header category file in another category. Just for "principe"

Comment: It's ok. Knowing whether it's 'correct' depends on the structure of your class. You may be better server having one .h for the private interface and multiple .m files to implement that interface, each of which imports the common .h file...